# Reading 2D array from a txt file using Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, 2d

```
from numpy import *

gradefile = open("f.txt", "r")
numExams = int(gradefile.readline())
numstudents = int(gradefile.readline())
examgrade = [[] * numstudents] * numExams

i = 0
for student in gradefile:
    grades = student.split()
    for j in range(numExams):
        examgrade[i][j] = int(grades[j])
    i += 1

gradefile.close()
```

txt file content:
7,
3,
90 96 92,
85 65 43,
54 44 77,
32 54 65,
32 65 76,
54 77 55,
44 87 98
*commas don't exist but it's a sign to the end of line.

> examgrade[i][j] = int(grades[j])
> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your wanting to do on this line

```
examgrade = [[] * numstudents] * numExams
```

but you can't multiply a list by a number.

Comment: examgrade = [[0 for i in range(numExams)] for j in range(numstudents)]
- i used this and raised the same error, the problem explanations: //drive.google.com/file/d/19PmTaiTPKk370wk4WgKUEl-PKnx7QxxX/view?usp=sharing